# Chrome put content in <td> on a new line. FF Doesn't

Tags: php, html

I'm creating an overview with data from a database.
But in Chrome (and Safari and Opera) 
The `<td></td>` content starts on a new line, while Firefox and IE(8) display it on the same line.

```
Name Event: <td>'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i,"event_title")).'</td>
Max # Persons: <td>'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i,"max_participants")).'</td>
Total Guests: <td>'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['total_guests']).'</td>    
Status Event: <td>'.$status.'</td>
```

Example:
**Chrome:**
*Name Event:

Wedding*

**FireFox:**
*Name Event: Wedding*

The same happens when I end every line with a `<br>` or `<br/>`

Is there a (easy) workaround to fix this?

Comment: Ok, but you use just `<td>` or you have anything in `<table>` and `<tr>` ?

Comment: This is what makes browsers cry.

Comment: Apart from the HTML problems, you're also using the wrong type of escaping. `mysql_real_escape_string` is for making queries. You're not making SQL, you're making HTML, so you want `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 8):

This is invalid HTML. How it will be rendered is totally undefined.

Inside a table, any text content must be inside `<td>` (or `<th>`) tags.

You need to put the labels into `<td>` tags as well, and wrap everything in `<tr>`s.

A complete mini-structure for a table would look like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name Event: </td><td>...</td>
  <td>Max # Persons:</td><td>...</td>
  <td>Total Guests:</td><td>...</td>
  <td>Status Event:</td><td>...</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest that you use <th>...</th> around the header fields.

Comment: @some: Pretty sure Pekka was just trying to keep things as simple as possible so the OP could understand the basic tag hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Table structure should be like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name Event: </td><td>'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i,"event_title")).'</td>
    <td>Max # Persons: </td><td>'.mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_result($result, $i,"max_participants")).'</td>
    <td>Total Guests: </td><td>'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['total_guests']).'</td>    
    <td>Status Event: </td><td>'.$status.'</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the complete code from the 'functions.php' file: [img] http://grab.by/6EBK  I don't think I'm able to do it like that...?

Comment: @Chris yes, but it should be easy enough to adjust. You simply need to wrap everything in `<td>`s

Comment: Just wrap "Naam Event:" as "<td>Naam Event:</td>" - note you also have an error at the end of your code, your br tag is missing a closing brace - <br/. In fact remove your br tags, they don't need to be there. Follow this tutorial, it looks like you need to get to the basics - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 1):

The reason it looks different in different browsers is that your HTML is invalid, so there's no guaranteed result - each browser will try to do their best to work out what you mean, but you can't be sure they'll come to the same conclusion.

`<td>` is supposed to be part of an HTML table. You should either restructure it so that everything is in correctly formatted `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags, or switch to using a different type of tag (there are several that could be suitable).

Either way, if you structure it correctly, it will render the same in different browsers.